# Raspberry Pi with Kinect

Tags: kinect, raspberry-pi

Could anyone get the camera data from the Kinect using a Raspberry Pi ?

We would like to make a wireless Kinect connecting it using Ethernet or WiFi. Otherwise, let me know if you have a working alternative.

Comment: Here's a great tutorial http://blog.tunpixel.tn/2014/10/27/kinect-rasp/

Comment: Was that the Kinect V1 ?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

To answer your question, yes it is possible to get Image and depth on the raspberry pi!

Here is how to.

If you want to use just video (color, not depth) there is already a driver in the kernel! You can load it like this:

```
modprobe videodev
modprobe gspca_main
modprobe gspca_kinect
```

You get a new /dev/videoX and can use it like any other webcam!

If you need depth (which is why you want a kinect), but have a kernel older than 3.17, you need another driver that can be found here: https://github.com/xxorde/librekinect.  If you have 3.17 or newer, then librekinect functionality is enabled by toggling the gspca_kinect module's command-line depth_mode flag:

```
modprobe gspca_kinect depth_mode=1
```

Both work well on the current Raspbian.

Comment: Just to make it clear, this is a (the only current) solution to use the kinect on slow embedded devices.

Comment: xxorde, can one combine your library for depth with librekinect for rgb?

Comment: I know it's a necro, but this is a top hit for rpi+kinect, so: librekinect was merged into Linux 3.17.  I've done an edit to note this, but it's waiting peer review.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.
Unfortunately I did't do much lately. I couldn't even test Antonio Ospite's upstream code because I do not own a kinect device myself.

When I want to review your suggestion it shows me: "You need at least 2k reputation to review suggested edits." I will have a look later and can edit it myself if necessary.

Answer (score 9):

If you can manage to plug your kinect camera to the raspberry Pi, install guvcview first to see if it does works.

```
sudo apt-get install guvcview
```

Then, type`guvcview` in the terminal and it should open an option panel and the camera control view. If all of that does works and that you want to get the RAW data to do some image treatments, you will need to compile OpenCV (it takes 4 hour of compiling) and after that, you just will need to program whatever you want. To compile it, just search on Google, there are lots of tutorial.

Answer (score 5):

Well, as far as I know there are no successful stories about getting images from Kinect on RaspberryPi.

On github there is an [issue](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect/issues/338) in libfreenect repository about such problem. In [this comment](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect/issues/338#issuecomment-22302723) user zarvox say that RPi haven't enough power to handle data from Kinect.

<s>Personally I tried to connect Kinect with RPi using [OpenNI2](https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI2) and [Sensor](https://github.com/PrimeSense/Sensor), but have no success.</s> And that was not a clever decision because it's impossible to work with Microsoft Kinect on Linux using OpenNI2 due to [licensing restrictions](http://community.openni.org/openni/topics/about_kinect_support_on_mac_linux) (Well, actually it is not so impossible. You can use [OpenNI2-FreenectDriver](https://github.com/piedar/OpenNI2-FreenectDriver) + OpenNI2 on Linux to hookup Kinect. But anyway this workaround is not suitable for RaspberryPi, because OpenNI2-FreenectDriver uses libfreenect).

But anyway there are some good tutorials about how to connect [ASUS Xtion Live Pro](http://wiki.ipisoft.com/Depth_Sensors_Comparison) to RaspberryPi: [one](http://mewgen.com/Ge107_files/20120921%20Setting%20up%20Rasberry%20pi%20for%20the%20Xtion%20and%20kinect.html), [two](http://www.hirotakaster.com/archives/2013/01/raspberry-pi-and-openni2.php). And how to connect Kinect to more powerfull arm-based CubieBoard2: [three](http://neon-society-electronics.com/?p=62).

Answer (score 2):

If you intend to do robotics the simplest thing is to use the Kinect library on ROS [Here](http://wiki.ros.org/kinect)

Oderwise you can try OpenKinect, They provide the libfreenect library that let you acess to the accelerometers the image & much more

[OpenKinect on Github here](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect)

[OpenKinect Wiki here](http://openkinect.org/wiki/Main_Page)

[Here](http://jonmacey.blogspot.fr/2012/07/raspberry-pi-and-kinect.html) is a good exemple with code & all the details you need to connect to the Kinect & operate the motors using libfreenect.

You will need a powered USB hub to power the Kinect & to install libusb.

A second possiblity is to use the [OpenNI](http://www.openni.org/) library which provides a SDK to develop midleware libraries to interface to your application there is even an OpenNi lib for processing [here](http://code.google.com/p/simple-openni/wiki/Installation).

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can use Kinect with raspberry pi in a small robotic project.
I have done this work with the openkinect library.
my experience is you should check your raspberry pi and monitoring pi voltage, not time does to low voltage.
you should accuracy your coding to use lower processing and run your code faster.
because if your code had got a problem, your image processing would be the slower response to the objects.
https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect/blob/master/wrappers/python/demo_cv2_threshold.py